# Can ttk radiobuttons be made to have style Toolbutton by default?

Tags: radio-button, default, tk-toolkit, ttk

I can set Toolbutton style for individual radiobuttons:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec /usr/bin/wish "$0" "$@"
set X11 /usr/X11/include/X11/bitmaps
image create bitmap LeftImage -file "$X11/left_ptr"
image create bitmap RightImage -file "$X11/right_ptr"
ttk::radiobutton .left -variable Foo -image LeftImage -style Toolbutton
ttk::radiobutton .right -variable Foo -image RightImage
pack .left .right
```

But I can't figure out how to make them all have Toolbutton style by default, ie, without having to specify it for every one separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can style 'TRadiobutton', which is the default style for radio buttons.

Comment: I'm not sure how.  Eg, this doesn't work: `ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -style Toolbutton`.  I'm new to styles...

Comment: ttk::style configure TRadiobutton -background magenta